# I need help for to optimize regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I´m creating a script for obsfucate php projects. I want to rename the variables, i´m trying but i cant.

For example ..

```
El día $dia me he comprando una $casaca en la tienda;
```

I want to change this for

```
El día $wdw_SDw_x me he comprando una $wdw_WsS en la tienda;
```

I have this code

```
if($v != 'this' && $v != 'GLOBALS' && $v != '_SERVER' && $v != '_GET' && $v != '_POST' && $v != '_FILES' && $v != '_REQUEST' && $v != '_SESSION'
    && $v != '_ENV' && $v != '_COOKIE' && $v != 'php_errormsg' && $v != 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ' && $v != 'http_response_header' && $v != 'argc' && $v != 'argv')
{
    $file_content = preg_replace(('/\W(\$' . $v . ')\W/'), ('$' . '_' . $v), $file_content);
    //$file_content = str_replace('$' . $v, '$' . md5($GLOBALS['key'] . $v), $file_content);
}
```

It´s working, but i need only to change words alone for example.

```
"return $this->db->query($sql)->row()->Total == 0 ? true : false;";
```

But is not working

```
return$_this->db->query$_sql->row()->Total == 0 ? true : false;
```

I dont want to change predefined variables like as:

$GLOBALS, $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST, $_FILES, $_REQUEST, $_SESSION, $_ENV, $_COOKIE, $php_errormsg, $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, $http_response_heade, $argc, $argv

Comment: Obfuscate PHP projects? For what purposes?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the '?' after the second `\W`, cause it's optional.

```
$file_content = preg_replace(('/\W(\$' . $v . ')\W?/'), ('$' . '_' . $v), $file_content);
```